# Carcassonne: The Grass Connection

Tags: carcassonne, carcassonne-river, carcassonne-catapult

Been looking into the rules a bit but can't find all the answers I want and it's possible this is more of a house rule with no definitive answer, but what I'm looking for is some official ruling if it exists.

Do grass continue under bridges? i.e. is the grass connected? I'm thinking of the bridges from for example River 2 that cross the river.

[image] [Source](http://boardgamegeek.com/image/123798/carcassonne-the-river-ii)

Also does the grass go around the well/pond from River expansions? Usually even if no other tiles connect the grass we do play as if the grass does connect on well/pond. [image] [source](http://boardgamegeek.com/image/205624/carcassonne-river-ii)

Do grass continue around the monastery from Catapult (that has the yellow fair thing stretching from one end to another)?

[image]
[Source](http://boardgamegeek.com/image/399169/carcassonne-catapult)

Finally Bridges, Castles and Bazaars I'm assuming grass under the wooden bridges does connect? [image]
[Source](http://boardgamegeek.com/image/763467/carcassonne-bridges-castles-and-bazaars)

There are a lot more pieces in the expansions that basically asks the same question about farmer grass. If there is no official ruling I'm still interested in what is most common out there.

Comment: I should mention perhaps the monastery from catapult only connects to grass on all sides as the yellow is nothing so normally this would be connected but placing it at the end where it is not yet connected you can then takeover the grass. Also in our case we had a road leading to it with one of those wooden bridge over so the only connection was through that tile

Comment: The link to the second image is not working anymore.

Comment: Found another that does show the pond so updated the post

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The rule in all cases is the same.

A field is contiguous only if there is an unbroken path of green on the tile(s).

The large wooden bridge does not interrupt the green so it does not break the field.  Everything else you mentioned does except for the path around the well/pond.

Answer (score 9):

I have a Carcassonne Big Box (containing The Tower, Inns & Cathedrals, Traders & Builders, and The Princess & the Dragon). I consulted those rules.

1. Fields do not continue past bridges. This is shown on page 7, using a tile that looks like a + of roads, one of them containing a bridge that looks like it could feasibly not split the field.

   > [emphasis theirs] The bridge is **not a crossing!** One road rune [sic] from left to right across the tile and the other runs from top to bottom across the tile. The **field segments** are all separated.
2. Fields do wrap around the edges of the River. This is stated on page 11.

   > The field space on the lake and spring tiles wraps around those features.

I cannot answer the Catapult question or the Bridges, Castles, and Bazaars question with authority. I would guess the Catapult ones are divided while the Castles ones are not.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes these rules can be confusing, but the iOS edition of Carcassonne has answered a lot of rule grey areas for me, including the River II city-bridge one.  The Carcassonne app makes it clear that this city-bridge over the river is, in fact, high enough to keep the fields *connected*.

While I still find this visually confusing sometimes, the app rules and application within games are clear.  This large bridge, as opposed to all small bridges, does *not* separate fields.

The pond end to the river also continues fields.

I can't answer your other questions with the same certainty, but I can say that my group and I have always played it that the wooden bridges you place over the tiles do not block fields.  But that's just my group.

(Since this post is years after you asked the question, you may all know those rules already, but I thought I'd add this just in case anyone's doing a search.)

Comment: Hi Rebecca, and welcome to the site. Check out our [tour] to learn a bit about how our site works. New answers to old questions are welcome for exactly the reasons you've described - Stack Exchange is attempting to build up a repository of knowledge for people in the future experiencing these problems, so this is all maintained for people doing a search as well.

Answer (score 1):

A city cuts a field in two, as does a road, even if it appears elevated in the drawing.  So that tile from River 2 has four fields on it.

However, if the field wraps around a feature on the tile--such as the lake at the end of the river, a cloister at the end of a road, or the river source--then the field is connected.

I haven't played with Catapult, but judging from the picture, it looks to me like that Cloister and the stuff connected to it *do* divide the field.  I'm sure the rules that came with that expansion address it.

Comment: ... and I honestly have no idea about the Bridges.  I didn't even know about that expansion yet.

Comment: The owner of the game wasn't sure I assumed he has checked the rules though but I guess I'll check if I can find a pdf of the rules from catapult expansion. The statement about an elevated road is from the rulebook?